# TCP Communication Behaviour

Tags: c#-4.0

I am sending data asynchronously over a TCP Socket.  I am currently connected to a SMSC simulator, on my local computer, just to check that all the packets are created correctly, before connecting to the real thing.

I am only sending a PDU once, and the SMSC receives it perfectly, and generates a response PDU and sends it back, but after that, an error Message pops up on the simulator specifying that it cannot receive 100 messages.  The problem is that I only send it once, there is no loop running that constantly sends the messages, and I have debugged and checked that it send only once.

I Think that the problem might be with the creation of the PDU.  I start by creating an byte array of size 1024, and then filling as necessary.  When filled up, it does not use the entire space of the array.  So I am thinking that when the simulator receives it, retrieves the data from the array, and then it reads the '0' bytes in the array after the actual data as a new message, since it gives me a response message saying that the data is not valid.

Is there anyway to avoid this, or am I just missing something here?  According to me, when receiving value in byte array, you should only use the necessary encoding to retrieve the data, and the rest of the '0' bytes should be ignored?

Sorry if my question is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the 0bytes in the array.

I solved it by removing the 0 bytes from the array, after reading an article posted on Stack Overflow:

Here is the Solution:

```
    private byte[] CleanArray(byte[] array)
    {
        int i = array.Length - 1;

        while (array[i] == 0)
        {
            i--;
        }

        byte[] cleanedArray = new byte[i + 1];
        Array.Copy(array, cleanedArray, i + 1);

        return cleanedArray;
    }
```